# textFieldShouldBeginEditing not being called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mobile

I am trying to use `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` to disable the keyboard from showing up for a custom `UITextField`. I'm implementing all the `UITextFieldDelegate` methods. However, for some reason, `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` actually never gets called.

The following delegate methods ALWAYS get called:

```
– textFieldDidBeginEditing:
– textFieldShouldEndEditing:
– textFieldDidEndEditing:
```

The view is structured in the following way:

`UIViewController` which holds a scrollview. Depending on the state of the view, this ScrollView will contain a `UIView` with a list of custom `UITextFields`.

I'm running iOS 4.3.5 (8L1) on this device.

Any ideas?

Edit; added some code snippets:

`UIViewController` has the following interface

```
@interface AViewController: UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Once the UIViewController loads, I connect all UITextFields to the view using

```
aSubView.aTextField.delegate = self;
```

(Simplified) delegate implementations located in AViewController

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return YES;
} 

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return YES;
}
```

Custom `UITextField` code

Simplified implementation file --

```
#import "PVEntryTextField.h"
#import "EntryViewController.h"

@implementation PVEntryTextField
@synthesize isPasswordField, state, singleTap;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)inCoder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:inCoder])
    {
         self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:19];
         self.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51.0/255.0 
                                         green:51.0/255.0 
                                          blue:51.0/255.0 
                                         alpha:1.0];
         self.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    }

    return self;
}

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + 16, bounds.origin.y,
                      bounds.size.width - 16*2 - 10, bounds.size.height);
}

- (CGRect) editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}

- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

- (void) updateState:(int) newState
{
     state = newState;
 }

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

 @end
```

Comment: If your other delegate methods are being called for the same textfield, and your textfields aren't subclasses or anything, this can only be from a typo in your method name.

Comment: I've subclassed UITextField to make some modifications to the look and feel of the textfield. However, I haven't actually touched anything related to delegates.

Comment: I am not sure about this but, is it posible that "textFieldShouldBeginEditing" is called by the default implementation of the method "canBecomeFirstResponder"? Try implementing the method by [super canBecomeFirstResponder] or just removing it.

Comment: You were correct. It's working now! Thanks! Write this as a reply and I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Is it posible that `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` is called by the default implementation of the method `canBecomeFirstResponder`?

Try implementing the method by `[super canBecomeFirstResponder]` or just removing it.

Comment: Thanks! I had a `UITextField` subclass that overrides `canBecomeFirstResponder` due to some empirical testing. Totally missed.

Comment: Iluismontero is absolutely correct! It appears that subclasses implementing the 'canBecomeFirstResponder' method should call super at some point in the logic. I hit exactly this same problem with a UITextField subclass and putting [super canBecomeFirstResponder] in my code fixed the problem.

Answer (score 13):

Have you set the UITextField delegate to "self"?

Comment: UITextField delegate is set to self. However, this is being called from the main UIViewController. Implementation of the delegate methods are also in the main UIViewController.

Comment: You must set the UITextView delegate to the class wich implements UITextViewDelegate methods

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that comes here and didn't find a solution. My problem was that I created the textField in IB and then alloc one in my viewDidLoad. When I removed the instantiation, the delegate worked correctly as it was tied to the correct TF.

```
//I REMOVED these two lines because I created the textfield in IB
_nameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
_priceTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];


[_nameTextField setDelegate:self];
[_priceTextField setDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into the issue of not having textFieldShouldEndEditing or textFieldShouldReturn called.  This occurred after updating my app's Storyboard.

The delegate methods were getting called when the UITextFields where part of the ViewController subclass.

But, when they were moved into a Scroll View within the ViewController, the methods were no longer called.

Setting their app delegates to self in ViewDidLoad fixed this problem.

```
self.emailField.delegate = self;
self.passwordField.delegate = self;
```

Comment: AMAZING.  In my situation, I have a view that's presented in a navigation controller, and nothing was working right... touch events, text boxes, etc.  I assigned the delegates as you suggested and it worked... wholly crap.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift-3 following method required "_" before textField so that this delegate method will call. In my case it helps me.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if is a typo error on copying the code here but the method name is incorrect:

CORRECT - textFieldShouldBeginEditing

YOURS - textFieldShoulBeginEditing (missing "d")