# UITextField Delegate not working

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have the following code:

```
@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell<UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtFields;
}

- (IBAction)textFieldAction:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *txtFields;

@end
```

I also have the following delegate function:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    return NO;
}
```

However, I notice that it's NEVER being called. I set the delegate from the interface builder as well as from code as per: `[txtFields setDelegate:self];` but neither seems to work. Is there something else i'm missing for this?

Comment: Are you using txtFields anywhere else?

Comment: Is the outlet connected?

Comment: @Ravi, it's not beign used anywhere else

Comment: @Tom, yep, the outlet was connected.

Comment: Well, that sounds strange. Checked if, by any chance, userInteractionEnabled is set to NO? Also, is the Keyboard popping up?

Comment: I noticed you are using it in a custom UITableViewCell, if you are creating the cell using Interface Builder, are you sure you've mapped the XIB file to your custom cell class?? this could be why the delegate is never getting called

Comment: is it a static cell or a dynamic cell? Are you using XIB or storyboards?

Comment: userInteractionEnabled is not NO, and keyobard is popping up. and I did map the xib to my class.... this is really strange. I'm sure its a stupid error but hard to find.

Comment: Where do you set the delegate? Do you set the delegate for every single cell when you in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method? Because you have many instances of that cell. Could you show the part where you programmatically set the delegate?

Comment: Did you look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743676/textfieldshouldbeginediting-not-being-called)? i.e. do you implement `canBecomeFirstResponder` in `MyCell`?

Comment: Is your `textFieldAction:` connected to the touch up inside event or some other event? Could potentially lead to a conflicting/overriding behavior.

Comment: Have you actually set the delegate of the UITextField to that class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are obviously using this in conjunction with a `UITableView`. First, if you want to support user interaction, the txtFields must be a subview of the cell's `contentView`, not the backgroundView.

Assuming that the txtFields object is a subview of the `contentView`, then lets look at the connections.

The tableView has a a method `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` where you either return a new cell or a recycled cell. At the very bottom of that cell, add:

```
NSLog(@"textFields=%@ delegate=%@", cell.txtFields, cell.txtFields.delegate);
assert(cell.txtFields.delegate == cell); // lets make sure this is proper
```

If in fact both arguments are there, you now know that the txtFields object is in the proper container (`contentView`), that the property is working, and that the delegate is set to the cell.

If that is all proper and you do not get the keyboard when you tap, then most likely something else is overlaying the txtFields - some other transparent view and its eating the touches.

In that case you should throw together a little demo app using the MyCell class, with even just one hardcoded cell, that demonstrates the problem, then upload that (zipped) to your DropBox account where others like myself can take a look at it and find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing:

> {
>       IBOutlet UITextField *txtFields;
>   }

since you have a `@property` already.

Also, did you `@synthesize txtFields;`?